# How to fill webform

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer-11

I want to update the fields in website using Excel values.

I found this macro online and tried to edit it.

How do I update fields once login is successful?

I have added following references:

- Microsoft HTML Object Library
- Microsoft Internet controls

I tried running it in IE8.

Received error:

> Method 'Document' of object 'IWebBrowser2' failed on line

I updated to IE11 and now the error is:

> "Automation error, unspecified error"

`IE.document.getelementsbyname("_58_login").Value = "jigarjigar"`

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal HWND As Long) As Long

Sub Automate_IE_Enter_Data()
    'This will load a webpage in IE
    Dim i As Long
    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim objElement As Object
    Dim objCollection As Object
    Dim HWNDSrc As Long
    Dim document As HTMLDocument
  
    'Create InternetExplorer Object
    Set IE = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")
    'Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 
    'True to make IE visible, or False for IE to run in the background
    IE.Visible = True
  
    'Navigate to URL
    IE.Navigate https://www.asite.com/login-home/
    ' Wait while IE loading...
    Do While IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
      
    'Get Window ID for IE so we can set it as activate window
    HWNDSrc = IE.HWND
      
    'Set IE as Active Window
    SetForegroundWindow HWNDSrc
      
   'Find & Fill Out Input Box
     
   IE.document.getelementsbyname("_58_login").Value = "jigarjigar"
   IE.document.getelementsbyname("_58_password").Value = "mypassword"
   IE.document.getelementsbyclassname("btn-submit nobgcolor").Click
   'Unload IE
endmacro:
   Set IE = Nothing
   Set objElement = Nothing
   Set objCollection = Nothing
      
End Sub
```

```html
 <table class="lfr-table">
    <tr>
        <td class="label-unm">
            Login (Email)
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="inp-login"><input name="_58_login" type="text" value="jigar@jigar.com" onblur="checkforGSUser(this)" autocomplete="off"/></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label-pass">
            Password
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="inp-login"><input id="_58_password" name="_58_password" type="password" autocomplete="off" value="" /></div>
            <span id="_58_passwordCapsLockSpan" class="pwdCapsMsgSpan" style="position:absolute;display:none;"><table width="111" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td class="pwdCapsBorder"><img src="/html/themes/asite/images/common/caps_msg_arrow.gif" hspace="10" /></td></tr><tr><td class="pwdCapsMsg">&#160;Caps Lock is on.</td></tr></table></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="div-submit">&#160;</div>
<div class="div-login-link">
    <input class="btn-submit nobgcolor" type="image" src="/html/themes/asite/images/common/login.gif" />
    <a target="_self" href="https://portal.asite.com/widget/web/guest/home?p_p_id=58&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&_58_struts_action=%2Flogin%2Fview&_58_cmd=forgot-password">Forgot Password?</a>
    <br/>
    <a href="https://www.asite.com/contactus" target="_top">Don't have an account?</a>
    <br/>
    <div class="clear-all"></div>
    <div class="clear-all"></div>
</div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: have you tried .InnerText?

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
Do While IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
```

Should be something like:

```
Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
```

In the `IE.ReadyState` enumeration, 4 = `READYSTATE_COMPLETE` so as it stands you're telling the code to *only* loop when the page has *finished* being served.

On this basis, the code will not wait while the page is being loaded (ReadyState 1 To 3) and chances are the element isn't available yet in the DOM when you come to edit it.

---

***Further Notes:***

- While you're at it, I'd probably change that `HWND` to a `LongPtr` in the API declaration too. (Assuming you are using a x64 version - if this is going to be used on other machines you will need to look at using conditional compilation).
- Also the `SetForegroundWindow` method returns a `Long` that should be checked to see of the message was sent successfully before continuing.
- Your DOM methods look wrong, you should be using:

  ```
  IE.Document.getElementById("_58_login").Value

  '// Class names don't have spaces in them, so the below is also wrong
  IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("btn-submit nobgcolor")(0).Click
  '// Or
  IE.Document.Forms(0).Submit
  ```
- DOM methods that have *plural* names (`getElements` <~~ notice the 's') return a HTMLColletion and need to be either iterated over and tested, or have an element access directly by using parethese containing the index of the item immediately after (as in the example above - note the index is zero-based)
- You don't actually close IE at any point, you just release the object from memory. Use `IE.Quit` to close the application before setting it to `Nothing`
- Finally, there's no need for the `endmacro:` label as you're not changing the error handling or directing the code at any point.

---

***After seeing HTML in OP:***

```
For Each el In IE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
    If el.Name = "_58_login" Then
        el.Value = "jigar@jigar.com"
        Exit For
    End If
Next

IE.Document.GetElementById("_58_password").Value = "Password"

IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("btn-submit nobgcolor")(0).Click

'// or IE.Document.Forms(0).Submit
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Macro Man. Since web form filling is new to me, I am facing problems. I changed the lines as follow:    IE.document.getElementsByName("_58_login")(0).Value = "jigar@jigar.com"
IE.document.getElementById("_58_password").Value = "*******"

And now i got error "Object variable or With block variable not set
Please help.

Comment: `getElementsByName` still isn't right - it should be `getElementsByClassName`. It depends on whether you're actually targeting the class/Id/tag attribute which method you use. Posting the html in your question would be more helpful

Comment: Now Getting "object required" error on line IE.Document.getElementById("_58_password").Value = "Password"

Comment: It's in a table, which is a bit more tricky to get - you will have to play around with getting diferent HTMLCollections and iterating through them.